# Read a file within a JAR

Tags: java

Now when I do this in eclipse it works just fine how I want it to, but when I export it into a jar file and run it, I get an error. I think this is because getting the file from a jar file is different.

Error I'm having

```
C:\Users\computer\res\levels\savelevel.png 
(The system cannot find the path specified)
```

My code

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png", 
 new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/res/levels/savelevel.png"));
```

What I am trying to do here is I am trying to write to an image using another image.

Comment: which error? post exception. File Not Found?

Comment: C:\Users\computer\res\levels\savelevel.png (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Just read any of the answers. They will help you. If you need to modify a jar you can use the jar tool (spin a sub process)

Comment: A .jar file is a zip file with some Java-specific entries.  An entry in a .jar file is not a separate file, just a sequence of bytes in a compressed archive, so you will never be able to read it as a java.io.File.  See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2433/resources-on-classpath#t=20160731193155774408&a=remarks .

Answer (score 1):

You should be using something like `getClass().getResource("a/path/relative/to/the/package/of/your/loading/class")` when you want to **read** something from a JAR. Now if you want to write, I can't remember if it's possible or not to mutate a file in the jar you are currently running in, but in any case I would strongly advise you not to do so.

As Srikanth pointed out, the jar must be available in your classpath, if that needs to be mentioned.

Comment: Well yeah, I'm assuming the jar in question is the jar the application is running from.

Comment: It need not be, as it's a image. Even in other case, he can add that jar in class path. Point is - Make a note to mention that jar should be in class path.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the case. `when I export it into a jar file` suggests he's exporting his application from Eclipse to an executable jar.

Answer (score 0):

geIO.write(image, "png", new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") Does not look inside the jar. It is a local filesystem path

Comment: Then how would i make it look into the jar?

Comment: Do a search about how to load a resource in java

Comment: @space1188 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html